# Capture selected area in Chrome and send it to my own server

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, plugins, screenshot

I want to capture a selected area on a web page, just like many chrome plugin do, such as [Lightshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lightshot-screenshot-tool/mbniclmhobmnbdlbpiphghaielnnpgdp?hl=en), [Fireshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/capture-webpage-screensho/mcbpblocgmgfnpjjppndjkmgjaogfceg?hl=en). I have two requirements:

1. To capture any selected area on the page
2. Send the captured image to my server so that I can retrieve it
3. (optional) annotation on the captured image

Previously I wanted to use javascript/jQuery to implement my own. The only thing I found was [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), but it does support capturing selected areas.

Then I turned for those plugins. They are quite nice since they do what I want and support annotations. However, they do not have a setting to send captured imaged to my server (they upload to their site, or google drive, or share on social media).

One thing I can do is to upload to their site, then download it to my server. However, I have problems again.

1. How can I detect when the user has clicked the 'upload' button so that the server can start downloading the image
2. How do I know the url of the uploaded image?

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked the google chrome extension capture api ?
desketop capture : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture

Comment: You mean I should develop my own chrome extension?

Comment: Ho I missunderstood your question. Yes you can do your own chrome extension but it's not very easy... Perhaps you can find an existing and open source one that you can modify ?